# Why is gcc not catching an exception from a multi target function?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, g++, clang

I'm using the `target` attribute to generate different function implementations depending on the CPU architecture. If one of the functions throws an exception it doesn't get caught if I compile with gcc, but with clang it works as expected.
If there is only a single implementation of the function it does work for gcc as well.

Is this a bug in gcc?

Example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z8f7vdn1z)):

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__attribute__((target("default")))
void f() {
    throw 1;

}

__attribute__((target("sse4.2,bmi")))
void f() {
    throw 2;
}

int main()
{
    try {
        f();
    }
    catch(... )
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output of gcc:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
```

Output of clang:

```
Caught exception
```

Comment: _"Support is only available in C++ for i386 targets"_ seems to imply that what you've tried on godbolt not supposed to work.

Comment: It also fails if I compile it for 32bit: https://godbolt.org/z/vznWT13c9 I'm pretty sure that in general 64 bit is also supported, because I have used it successfully in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this and a GCC developer confirmed it as a bug: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106627)

For now a workaround seems to wrap the function and use the `gnu::noipa` attribute to disable interprocedural optimizations:

```cpp
__attribute__((target("default")))
void f() {
    throw 1;
}

__attribute__((target("sse4.2")))
void f() {
    throw 2;
}
[[gnu::noipa]]
void f1()
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    try {
        f1();
    }
    catch(... )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The bug is now fixed in gcc's master branch and should be released with gcc version 13.